# How to remove everything inside a div, without deleting the div itself, using only JavaScipt and not jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Question is pretty clear. Given a div, how to remove all the elements/children inside it, without deleting the div?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Although a valid solution, this assumes the div has an ID of course

Comment: @MichaëlHompus ID is available